# Deploy WebObjects applications on Mavericks

Tags: deployment, osx-mavericks, webobjects

Has anyone done it?  If so, can you please direct me to some instructions.  I was able to deploy on Lion but had no luck on Mavericks.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real difference in Mavericks or any of the other OS X versions. The only Gotcha was making sure you were editing the correct httpd.conf file. Apple did a good job of obfuscating the file locations.

Here is a good start:

http://brianflove.com/2013/10/23/os-x-mavericks-and-apache/

then follow the instruction at:

http://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/WO/WO+5.4+Getting+Started#WO5.4GettingStarted-javamonitor

i would leave another link, but stack overflow is complaining that I don't have that privilege.

check the wiki.wocommunity.org